# Swift best practice for multiply inheriting inits and deinits?

Tags: swift, protocols, multiple-inheritance

I have two classes that ideally would have code in their `inits` and `deinits`, e.g.:

```
class Tappable {
    init() { Registry.register(tappable: self) }
    deinit { Registry.deregister(tappable: self) }
}
class Resizable {
    init() { Registry.register(resizable: self) }
    deinit { Registry.deregister(resizable: self) }
}
```

Ideally I would inherit from both, e.g.:

```
class UIElement: Tappable, Resizable {}
```

But of course I can't in Swift. My current solution is to make one a protocol and put a note in to remind me to write `init` and `deinit` with calls to the `Registry`, e.g.:

```
//: Classes that implememt `Resizable` must call `Registry.register(resizable: self)` in all `init`s and have `deinit { Registry.deregister(resizable: self) }`.
protocol Resizable {}
class UIElement: Tappable, Resizable {
    override init() {
        super.init()
        Registry.register(resizable: self)
    }
    deinit { Registry.deregister(resizable: self) }
}
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3):

You could create a composite class and store your Registry classes as variables, it could look something like this:

```
protocol Register {
    init(_ target: UIElement)
    func deregister(target: UIElement)
}
class Tappable: Register {
    required init(_ target: UIElement) { Registry.register(tappable: target) }
    func deregister(target: UIElement) { Registry.deregister(tappable: target) }
}
class Resizable: Register {
    required init(_ target: UIElement) { Registry.register(resizable: target) }
    func deregister(target: UIElement) { Registry.deregister(resizable: target) }
}

class UIElement {
    var traits: [Register]!
    override init() {
        self.traits = [Tappable(self), Resizable(self)]
    }
    deinit {
        self.traits.forEach { $0.deregister(self) }
    }
}
```

This way, when deinit is called on the `UIElement` object, all of the traits of `UIElement` will be deregistered.

---

You can test this out in a Swift Playground by adding the following at the bottom. This will create the UIElement class, have it register for the traits, and then deallocate it and have it deregister!

```
var test: UIElement! = UIElement()
test = nil
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have each protocol define a required initializer:

```
protocol Tappable {
    init(r:Registry)
}
```

Then any class that inherits the protocol will have to implement that initializer, which you'd hope would remind you what needed to happen there.

That doesn't work particularly-well for UIView subclasses, which need to implement UIView's designated initializers, also.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it is certainly a good reminder. I will use the idea when I can, but I don't always want to have an init with an exact signature. A nice side effect of the idea is that it forces dependency injection, which at times I also want. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution, which replaces your two superclasses with a single superclass, and an OptionSet. Obviously, this gets a bit unwieldy if you need to do a lot of case-specific initialization and de-initialization, but it works *okay* for the example given.

```
class Registry {
    class func register(resizeable: Any) {

    }
    class func register(tappable: Any) {

    }
}

struct ViewTraits: OptionSet {
    let rawValue: Int
    init(rawValue: Int) { self.rawValue = rawValue }
    static let Tappable = ViewTraits(rawValue: 1)
    static let Resizeable = ViewTraits(rawValue: 2)
}

protocol Traits {
    var traits:ViewTraits { get }
}

class TraitedView: NSView, Traits {
    var traits:ViewTraits {
        get {
            fatalError("Must implement a getter for Traits")
        }
    }
    private func register() {
        if (traits.contains(.Tappable)) {
            Registry.register(tappable: self)
        }
        if (traits.contains(.Resizeable)) {
            Registry.register(resizeable: self)
        }
    }
    override init(frame:NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        register()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        register()
    }
}

class MyView: TraitedView {
    override var traits: ViewTraits {
        get {
            return [ViewTraits.Resizeable, ViewTraits.Tappable]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I can probably do something like this.

Answer (score 0):

I have pinched everyones ideas in the playground below. Thanks.

```
var sequence = ""
enum Registry {
    static func register(tappable _: Tappable) { sequence += "reg. tap.\n" }
    static func deregister(tappable _: Tappable) { sequence += "dereg. tap.\n" }
    static func register(resizable _: Resizable) { sequence += "reg. res.\n" }
    static func deregister(resizable _: Resizable) { sequence += "dereg. res.\n" }
}
class Registrar {
    init() {
        if let tappable = self as? Tappable {
            Registry.register(tappable: tappable)
        }
        if let resizable = self as? Resizable {
            Registry.register(resizable: resizable)
        }
    }
    deinit {
        if let tappable = self as? Tappable {
            Registry.deregister(tappable: tappable)
        }
        if let resizable = self as? Resizable {
            Registry.deregister(resizable: resizable)
        }
    }
}
protocol Tappable {
    func tap()
}
extension Tappable {
    func tap() { sequence += "tap\n" }
}
protocol Resizable {
    func resize()
}
extension Resizable {
    func resize() { sequence += "resize\n" }
}
class UIElement: Registrar, Tappable, Resizable {
}
var uie: UIElement! = UIElement()
uie.tap()
uie.resize()
uie = nil
sequence // "reg. tap.\nreg. res.\ntap\nresize\ndereg. tap.\ndereg. res.\n"
```